# http 404 found tomcat 8.5

Tags: java

When I try to enter the website http://localhost:8080/CrunchifySpringMVCTutorial

This is what I get from the browser:

```
HTTP Status [404] – [Not Found]

Type Status Report

Message /CrunchifySpringMVCTutorial

Description The origin server did not find a current representation for the target resource or is not willing to disclose that one exists.

Apache Tomcat/8.5.15
```

This is what I have tried and it still didn't work:
Exported the project to a war file and deployed to tomcat by putting the war file in the webapp folders.

Comment: the only valid response to this is *so?*

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please read [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) before attempting to ask more questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add the file in the `web.xml` file under the `welcome-file-list` tags so that the server knows to display the page for the user.

```
<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>/CrunchifySpringMVCTutorial/index.jsp</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
```

Your `web.xml` file should live within your `WEB-INF` folder.

Comment: Hi, Sorry this was my first time to use stackoverflow to ask questions so I was not familiar with formatting. Thank you for your response! But I have added tags and the web.xml in my projects but it still didn't work.

Comment: Make sure the path to the page is correct, try a couple different combinations. Maybe try just having `index.jsp` in there and also make sure that you are navigating to the `index.jsp` file on your server, not the full file path.

Comment: the Answer box is for *Answers* and **not guesses**! There is absolutely no way to know what is wrong with this persons environment given what they have posted much less how to fix it.